# Query for all Nobel Peace Prize recipients in Freebase

Tags: freebase, mql

I want to query all recipients of the Nobel Peace Prize and the date (year) from Freebase. I looked at the [site](https://www.freebase.com/m/05f3q?props=&lang=en&filter=/award/award_category/winners), which shows me all winners, but if I do the query [here](https://www.freebase.com/query), I do only get "null" results!

What I have so far:
    [{
        "id": "/m/05f3q",
        "/award/award_category/winners": []
    }]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [schema](https://www.freebase.com/award/award_category/winners?schema=) for the information that you're trying to query, you can see that what you are getting back is actually an Award Honor object which has a schema like [this](https://www.freebase.com/award/award_honor/?schema=).  It's got a bunch of different properties, but it doesn't have any meaningful name which is why it's coming back as null.

Try something more along the lines of [the below](https://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?lang=/lang/en&q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/award/award_honor%22,%22award%22%3a%7B%22id%22%3a%22/m/05f3q%22%7D,%22award_winner%22%3a%5B%7B%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull%7D%5D,%22year%22%3anull%7D%5D) (add additional properties as needed):

```
[{
  "type": "/award/award_honor",
  "award": {
    "id": "/m/05f3q"
  },
  "award_winner": [{
    "id": null,
    "name": null
  }],
  "year": null
}]
```

Comment: Ah Thank you! Do you know why the query returns only 97 results, where the site shows me 101?

Comment: A second question before you've even accepted the first answer?

Comment: Well, your query could be wrong, if it returns less results then shown in the GUI of Freebase. Of course I will accept your answer if this is not the case.

Comment: Did you compare the two lists?  I suspect not since the difference would have been obvious.  The query above doesn't include nodes which have no winner specified (ie bogus records).  If you want to include them, add "optional":true to the award_winner sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
  "id": "/en/nobel_prize_in_economics",
  "/award/award_category/winners": [{
    "/award/award_honor/award_winner": [],
    "/award/award_honor/year": null,
    "/award/award_honor/award": null,
    "/award/award_honor/honored_for": []
  }]
}]
```

I cannot do it in just one call, so I do the same for "/en/nobel_prize_in_physiology_or_medicine", "/en/nobel_prize_in_chemistry", "/en/nobel_peace_prize", "/en/nobel_prize_in_literature".